# Are there DBSet.UpdateAsync() and RemoveAsync() in .net core?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, async-await

I could not find any info on this anywhere.

There are `ToListAsync(),` `AddAsync()` and more, but could not find any documentation about `UpdateAsync()` or `RemoveAsync().`

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: SaveChangesAsync is what you're looking for.

Comment: So, i call dataset.Update() and then dataset.SaveChangesAsync()?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`ToListAsync` exists because it actually causes EF to head off to the data store to retrieve the data. This may take some time, hence why you can call it asynchronously.

`AddAsync` however, only begins tracking an entity but won't actually send any changes to the database until you call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`. You shouldn't really be using this method unless you know what you're doing. The reason the async version of this method exists is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet_1_AddAsync__0_System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

[`Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet_1_Update__0_) and [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet_1_Remove__0_) are the same as `Add` in as much as they only affect the internal tracking until you save the changes you've made.

Comment: So `AddAsync` could fetch an auto-generated value (autoincrement key etc.) from the server without calling `SaveChanges` for example?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I believe it is used when you are using [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) as you can get a number from them before you insert into a table. You won't be able to get an auto-incremented key without saving changes first.