# How can I use a DBContext.Remove() asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I am trying to delete an entity using my DBContext.Remove() asynchronously but I can't compile it.

```
public async void Delete(Bank bank) {
    await BankContext.Remove(bank);
}
```

I get the following error:

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'EntityEntry' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityEntry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no async version of Remove (if there was, it would be called RemoveAsync).

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034282/are-there-dbset-updateasync-and-removeasync-in-net-core) and in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet_1_AddAsync__0_System_Threading_CancellationToken_),  AddAsync only exists to 'to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously', so I assume there was no need for RemoveAsync.

```
public void Delete(Bank bank)
{
    BankContext.Remove(bank);
}
```